# How do I create a multi-select checkbox field in a content entity?

Tags: 8, entities

Trying to figure out how to have 'Desktop', 'Mobile', and 'N/A' as check boxes on a config entity form in drupal 8, where I can select one or more options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This configuration worked for me:

```
 $fields['device'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create("list_string")
      ->setSetting('allowed_values', ['desktop'=>'Desktop', 'mobile'=>'Mobile', 'na'=>'N/A'])
      ->setLabel('Device')
      ->setDescription('Select associated devices')
      ->setRequired(TRUE)
      ->setCardinality(-1)
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'options_buttons',
        'weight' => 6
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
```